# How to use the law of diffusion in the presence of electric forces?

Tags: physiology, biophysics

Isn't the movement of ions affected by the electric field as well? For instance, when a sodium channel in a cell's membrane opens, the sodium ions are said to diffuse into the cell, from higher extracellular concentration to lower intracellular concentration. But what about the electric force fields? The negative ions within the cell attract the sodium ions outside the cell, while the potassium ions within the cell repel them, so why aren't such interactions mentioned and taken into account when discussing the direction or intensity of flow? It seems that the only factor considered by books is diffusion of sodium ions from higher to lower concentration.

Comment: Sure, the electric force matters a lot. Ions, like protons H+, follow their respective Ion Motive Force, which is the sum of two components: difference in concentration (osmosis) and difference in charge (voltage) across the membrane. You can find more details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemiosmosis).